# Events in ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, code-behind, resourcedictionary

I have a `DataTemplate` in a `ResourceDictionary`. Now I have a `GroupBox` in the template, on which I want to use the `MouseDown` event. But the `ResourceDictionary` has no code behind
(as intended) and no link to the code behind of the file where I use the things from the dictionary.

How do I use this event?

Comment: perhaps use an attached property/behavior?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this applies to you but i had a similar case.
I wanted to use MouseDown event on every labels of my ListBox.
So here's what i did : I setted the ListBox.ItemTemplate to a ContentPresenter.
Then i used MouseDown event on that ContentPresenter. I setted the ContentPresenter's ContentTemplate
to the DataTemplate of my label and it worked well, thus separating my DataTemplate from my MouseDown event.

```
<ListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myLabelTemplate}"
                MouseDown="Event">
            </ContentPresenter>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Sorry for my bad english ;)